# How to get public key in Google pay integration with Direct token specification approach

Tags: android, google-pay

I am trying to integrate google pay in my android app. I want to integrate google pay without any payment gateway in between (means DIRECT approach rather than PAYMENT_GATWAY token specification). I found DIRECT method integration code on official site. In that google asks for protocolVersion and publicKey as parameter and below i found that i can get my public key in my Google Pay Developer Profile. I searched for Google Pay Developer account but unable to found public key Anyone can help me to get public key for google pay DIRECT integration?

```
private static JSONObject getTokenizationSpecification() {
  JSONObject tokenizationSpecification = new JSONObject();
  tokenizationSpecification.put("type", "DIRECT");
  tokenizationSpecification.put(
      "parameters",
      new JSONObject()
          .put("protocolVersion", "ECv2")
          .put("publicKey", "replace with public_key"));

  return tokenizationSpecification;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am looking for same ..

Comment: have anyone got an answer for this ????

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to an answer that I provided to the following question: [Where is Google pay Developer account and how to generate public key to upload in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/where-is-google-pay-developer-account-and-how-to-generate-public-key-to-upload-i/58457094#58457094)

Adding a public key to your Google Pay Developer Profile:

> The public key needs to be added to both the Google Pay Developer Profile and included as part of the payment request: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#direct
>
> Note that you need to be registered with Google Pay for `DIRECT` integration.
>
> Example:
>
> ```js
> "tokenizationSpecification": {
>   "type": "DIRECT",
>   "parameters": {
>     "protocolVersion": "ECv2",
>     "publicKey": "BOdoXP1aiNp.....kh3JUhiSZKHYF2Y="
>   }
> }
> ```

Generating a public key:

> The following link provides details on how to generate a public key using OpenSSL: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#using-openssl
>
> Important bits:
>
> ```sh
> # generate private key
> openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
>
> # generate a base64-encoded public key
> openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub:" -A5 | sed 1d | xxd -r -p | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -
> ```